# debezium 1.2 for postgres 10 connector

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium

I have a Postgres 10 version and trying to set up debezium connector with Kafka.

Below are the setting that I made

```
Set Wal_level = 'logical'
```

created a replication slot :

```
SELECT * FROM pg_create_logical_replication_slot('slot_repl', 'test_decoding');
```

debezium connector :

```
{
    "name": "cid-staging-connector",
    "config": {
      "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
      "database.hostname": "localhost",
      "database.port": "5433",
      "database.user": "postgres",
      "database.password": "xxxx",
      "database.server.id": "54111",
      "database.server.name": "postgres",
      "database.dbname": "postgres",
      "table.whitelist": "public.product",
      "plugin.name": "wal2json",
      "database.history.consumer.security.protocol":"SASL_SSL",
      "database.history.producer.security.protocol":"SASL_SSL",
      "database.history.consumer.sasl.mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-512",
      "database.history.producer.sasl.mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-512",
    "database.history.consumer.sasl.jaas.config":"org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"xxx\" password=\"xxx\";",
      "database.history.producer.sasl.jaas.config":"org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"XXX\" password=\"xxx\";",
      "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "xxx",  
      "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.cid_staging",
    }
}
```

But getting the below error

**error_code":500,"message":"Couldn't obtain encoding for database postgres"**

Comment: Did you install wal2json plugin?

Comment: Yes. cloned https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json. 2) compiled wal2json by editing wal2json.vcxproj file and changed c:\postgres\pg103 to the PostgreSQL prefix directory.  3)opened this project file in MS Visual Studio and compiled it. copied wal2json.dll to the pg_config --pkglibdir directory.

Comment: Also added the below lines in pg_hba.conf host all all all md5
host replication postgres 0.0.0.0/0 trust and ran alter table product replica identity full

Comment: Also please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62787477/7109598